# Reorder rows in Table and then save the table in this order in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: Picture of the questions table]

Hey I want to reorder my table like that

```
SELECT * FROM questions
ORDER BY field(questionsId, 3, 2, 1)
```

and update this table in that order in my db.
How do I do this?

Comment: You can´t store data in your db in the order you want (it doesn ´t make sense) You allways can use ORDER BY to get your data in the order you want

Comment: Ordering in the DB doesn't indeed make sense. In your case add a `ASC` or `DESC` statement to sort/reverse sort, eg `SELECT * FROM questions ORDER  BY questionsId DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering.  Period.  If you run a `SELECT` query with no `ORDER BY`, then the results are in an indeterminate order.  Even if they look like they are in some order (say insertion order), you cannot depend on that.

This is even true of a clustered index which stores the data on the data pages in a particular order.  That ordering is not guaranteed.

What you can do is to store an additional column with the ordering you want and then use that in the `ORDER BY`:

```
alter table questions add column my_ordering int as
     (field(questionsId, 3, 2, 1));
```

Then you can easily use this for ordering:

```
select q.*
from questions q
order by my_ordering;
```

You can even use `my_ordering` in a column to speed up queries (on large data sets) that return results in that order.